# DataGridViewColumn loses data

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, datacolumn

I have a dataGridView that loads its data from an SQL server with the Data Source utility:

[image: Correctly loaded data]

However when I trigger the following code:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM AssetManagement_copy";

                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    sda.Fill(filteredTable);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = filteredTable;
                }
            }
```

The Serial No. column of the dataGridView loses its data?
[image: DataGridView with lost data]

Any ideas as to why this might be happening? I don't do any specific column manipulation or specify any dataColumn in the code to do anything with.

Thanks all!

Comment: just recheck your code it seems your missing something at **filteredTable** , but your preparing query with string sql .

Comment: When I load the dataTable with the above code on startup the table loads missing this column also, but this exact code was working fine up until just yesterday, and the database it comes from hasn't been edited :/

Comment: Edit: when I fill the table with the DataSource utility with: this.assetManagementTableAdapter.Fill(this.balticTelephoneDataSet1.AssetManagement_copy);   
The first column disappears again, though this is the exact code that loads the correct data on form load